# Устранить ошибку AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Пытаюсь запустить на сервере Debian 8 следующий код:

```Python
import utils
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True ,commands=['code'])
def markup_code(message):
    markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    markup.add('Зашифровать')
    markup.add('Расшифровать')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Действие', reply_markup=markup)
    utils.set_active_user(message.chat.id, 'active_command')
    insert_to_db(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    utils.count_rows()
    random.seed()
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

После запуска выдает ошибку: `AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'`. Использую Python 3.4.

[pyTelegramBotAPI 2.3.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyTelegramBotAPI)

Сама реализация осуществлялась локально на Windows, но на нём всё работает. Все модули установил.

Comment: Версии ПО приведите. Ссылку на документацию, где показан `TeleBot.message_handler` покажите для вашей версии.

Comment: @jfs добавил в описание

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/issues/278

Answer (score 9):

Была такая же ошибка. Если библиотека не ставиться, не забывайте делать `apt-get update`, после этого и `pip` установился и `pip3`. Был установлен только `telebot`. Устанавливал так `pip3 install telebot`.  А ошибка ушла после `pip3 install PyTelegramBotAPI` и скрипт запустился.