# Телеграм бот не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Неделю назад се работало. Вводишь дату, получаешь на нее праздник. И вдруг перестало работать. Никто ничего не менял: Другой бот работает, именно этот не хочет. В чем дело? Вот код:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):

    try:
        if message.text:
            send = str(message.text)

        if send[0] == "0" and send:
            send = send[1::]
        data = bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, slovar.data_year.get(send))
        bot.register_next_step_handler(data, func)
    except BaseException as e:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Введите дату в формате Д.ММ или ДД.ММ и нажмите ENTER")
```

Вот лог:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/chatbot/holidays.py", line 9, in <module>
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message_handler'
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Устранить ошибку AttributeError: 'TeleBot' object has no attribute 'message\_handler'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620623/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-attributeerror-telebot-object-has-no-attribute-message-hand)

Comment: Покажите весь код, где вы инициализируете переменную bot.

Comment: @MyZik bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

Comment: @СергейБогданов решение, которое отправили выше не помогло?

Comment: @ MyZik нет, не помогло. попробовал во всех вариациях.